# Guardar datos en distintas tablas en django

Tags: html, python, django

Les comento mi problema a ver si pueden ayudarme. Tengo un proyecto en Django en el que me conecto con una base de datos con 2 tablas las cuales completo con forms (1 por cada tabla). La cosa es que llamo a los 5 forms en un mismo template, con el método POST. Mi pregunta es: Cómo puedo guardar lo que se llenó en cada form en la tabla correspondiente? O sea, si utilizo Form1(request.POST), puedo guardar correctamente en la primer tabla, pero ya el segundo form no me lo reconoce.

Este es el template:

```html
<form class="forms" action="{% url 'guardado' %}" method="POST">
 {% csrf_token %}
            
 <div class="form-container">
  <div class="form_paciente form">
   {% for row in paciente %}
     <div class="{{row.id_for_label}}">
      {{row.label_tag}} {{row}}
     </div>
   {% endfor %}
  </div>
 </div>
            
 <div class="form-container">
  <div class="form_datos form">
   {% for row in datosGrales %}
    <div class={{row.id_for_label}}>
     {{row.label_tag}} {{row}}
    </div>
   {% endfor %}
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-md-2 justify-self-end">Guardar</button>

</form>
```

Este el views.py:

```py
def guardarPac(request):

 if request.method == 'POST':
  paciente = FormPaciente(request.POST)
  datos = FormDatos(request.POST)
        
  if paciente.is_valid():
   post = paciente.save(commit=False)
   mensaje = f" Paciente '{post.apellido}, {post.nombre}' guardado con éxito!"
   post.domicilio = f'{post.localidad}, {post.calle} {post.altura}'
   id_pac = post.ID
   post.save()

  if datos.is_valid():
   post = datos.save(commit=False)
   post.paciente = id_pac
   post.save()

 return render(request, "home.html", {#'mensaje':mensaje,
                                   'paciente':Paciente.objects.all(),
                                         'users': ser.objects.all()})
```

Acá el form "paciente" lo guarda correctamente, pero el segundo ("datos") no me lo toma como válido.

Se me ocurre que guardando todo en una misma tabla, o utilizando diferentes templates, podría solucionarlo fácilmente, pero por temas del proyecto creo que conviene tenerlo en tablas separadas y me gustaría poder conservarlo en un sólo

Comment: Para que puedan ayudarte, Por favor intenta desarrollar  tu problema con código fuente, las partes que te parezcan relevates, y fíjate también el log de consola del navegador, espero poder ayudarte

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: que error te manda? `id_pac`  debes definirlo al principio del metodo! `id_pac=None`

Comment: @Bryro no manda ningún error, sólo no toma el 2do form como válido (no pasa la sentencia `if datos.is_valid()` y por lo tanto no me lo guarda en la db.

Por qué debería estar el principio la definición de `id_pac`?